# I am accepting userId as a parameter in express js but getting 401 statusCode

Tags: node.js, api, express, backend

I am accepting user Id as a parameter here, but getting status 401. Please help.

In routes/users.js

```
router.get("/?:id", users.getUserById);
```

the users controller is:

```
const getUserById = async (req, res) => {
  let result;
  try {
    result = await userQuery.fetchUser({ userId: req.params.userId });
  } catch (error) {
    logger.error(`Error while fetching user: ${error}`);
    return res.boom.serverUnavailable("Something went wrong please contact admin");
  }

  if (!result.userExists) {
    return res.boom.notFound("User doesn't exist");
  }

  const { phone = "", email = "", ...user } = result.user;
  try {
    user.phone = obfuscate.obfuscatePhone(phone);
    user.email = obfuscate.obfuscateMail(email);
  } catch (error) {
    logger.error(`Error while formatting phone and email: ${error}`);
    return res.boom.badImplementation("Error while formatting phone and email");
  }

  return res.json({
    message: "User returned successfully!",
    user,
  });
};
```

Output of the above code is as follows: Please help I am new to backend Development.

```
{
    "statusCode": 401,
    "error": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "Unauthenticated User"
}
```

Comment: nowhere in the code you have shown sets that response, also if its `:id` it would be `req.params.id`, not `userId`

Comment: also your doing `...user`, and `user.phone = obfus..` etc `user` is not defined anywhere

Comment: @LawrenceCherone user is defined in this file. I changes :id to :userId but getting same error

Answer (score 2):

your parameter is not userId its only id

```
//you can do this 

result = await userQuery.fetchUser({ userId: req.params.id});

//or you can do this 

const {id}  = req.params
result = await userQuery.fetchUser({ userId: id });
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, But this is still not working

Comment: ok i realy do not now what userQuery.fetchUser() is ... but if you use User.findOne({ userId : req.params.id}) it might work if User is your user model and you have userId in your model